# jQuery .find and .nextUntil Together

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using ajax to get the contents of an external file, and then grabbing one element from the string and loading that into an element on my page using jQuery's `find()`. This is working great, but now I'm needing to get everything between one element and another from the external file, I've tried using `.nextUntil()`, but it's not stopping at the right element, and is grabbing the entire rest of the document. So the question is, can I do this, or is there another way I should do it?

```
...
success: function(result) {
     html = $(result),
         comp = $(html).find("#comp1").nextUntil(".comp-close");
     $('.output-text').html(comp);
},
...
```

Comment: This sounds like you're using the wrong selector in `nextUntil()` if the first part works, maybe double-check that `.comp-close` is really a sibling of the initial element?

Comment: Also, doing a .find on an ID until something is probably not good, because ID's should be unique within the document. So you could never have to find more than one.

Comment: Could you give us a JSFiddle?

Comment: As it turns out, there was one stray html tag between my two selectors that broke everything! Duhh...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably that ".comp-close" is not a direct sibling.

I validated this behavior here :

```
<div id="1"></div>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<div>
  <p>4</p>
  <div id="2"></div>
  <p>5</p>
</div>
<div id="3"></div>
<p>6</p>

<p>=====</p>
<div id="4"></div>
```

---

```
// Clones until the end of the document
//var list = $('#1').nextUntil("#2");

// Clones until #3 since it is a direct sibling
var list = $('#1').nextUntil("#3");

console.log(list)

// Clone if you do not want to remove the originals from the DOM
$('#4').append(list.clone());
```

---

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6gzg74vj/42/#&togetherjs=BJ0tlkuq9k)

Also note that you should use clone() if you do not want to modify the DOM.

Hope this helped!